# What is the difference between -h, -r, -s, and -k, in the "shutdown now" command in single-user mode?

Tags: macos, shutdown, single-user

So, I opened up single-user mode to show my friend how easy it was for a Mac to be directly hijacked if someone was able to steal the physical lap top (as opposed to hijacking remotely using SSH), and I couldn't exactly remember which `shutdown now` *option* to use (fortunately, I was prompted by the command line), so I defaulted to `-h`. Should I be worried if I use `-h` instead of `-r`? Is there any difference between these commands?

```
shutdown -h now
shutdown -s now
shutdown -r now
shutdown -k now
```

Comment: What in shutdown's manual page do you find unclear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [shutdown manual page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/shutdown.8.html) (`man shutdown`entered in a Terminal window):

```
 -h      The system is halted at the specified time.

 -k      Kick everybody off.  The -k option does not actually halt the
         system, but leaves the system multi-user with logins disabled
         (for all but super-user).

 -r      The system is rebooted at the specified time.

 -s      The system is put to sleep at the specified time.
```

So to shutdown the Mac the `-h` option is the proper one. `-r` restarts it and `-s` puts it to sleep. The `-k` option doesn't halt your system at all.

Answer (score 1):

Not much happens in single user mode - so I just just use a simpler command:

```
halt
```

The `shutdown` command is for sequencing a lot of the scaffolding that is erected to have the system processes start in a certain order, then user processes. Even with `launchd` simplifying much on OS X, all of this is relevant to full blown OS X - notice to allow programs to save work, close files, check point logs so that the next start has less work to do.

***None of that matters in single user mode*** as halt flushes the IO and takes down the power to the hardware.